# How to position buttons on scaled background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Starting in Android development, i wonder how to do this layout in XML (using Android Studio), targeting 4.x Android devices.

How to precisely position 4 buttons on a bitmap background? Should work despite bitmap scaling.

Scenario:
My application main screen should consist of 4 buttons placed on a bitmap. Button positioning should always look exactly like this, and the whole should scale up/down (proportional width/height) to match the screen space. A layout sketch:

[image: layout sketch]

Tried solutions:

- 4 Buttons in a GridLayout with background:

  ```
  <GridLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:columnCount="2"
      android:rowCount="2">

      <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button1" />

      <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button2" />

      <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button3" />

      <Button android:id="@+id/button4"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button4" />
  </GridLayout>
  ```
- 4 Buttons in a GridLayout, above a ImageView in a RelativeLayout.
- One ImageView with onTouch() that checks a colorcoded bitmap. ([source here](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/))

The only solution that worked ok regarding scaling is the onTouch(), but i'd rather keep using actual buttons so keyboard navigation and press/hover effects work as expected.

How is it possible to position buttons, to have them always match scale with the bitmap?
Thanks for any insights.

Due to the title this question looks like a dupe but i havent found any that demonstrate how this can be accomplished.

Comment: why dont you try relative layout instead of grid layout ?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I mathed my way around it. It's pretty horrible but let's say that your background image is 500x500px and on an image like that your button is supposed to be at (100, 100) with a size of 50x50px relative to that background image. When you lay it out you have to get the size of the current device, let's say it's 700x800px in size (these devices most likely do not exist). In this case you would have to set the width of your button to (700/500)*50px and the height would be (800/500)*50px . The position of the button would then be at (700/500)*100 and (800/500)*100 .

You are pretty much scaling the button with the background image. Hopefully I'm making myself clear :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, hope will help

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/notificationform_btn_Approve"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/btn_approve"
android:onClick="btnApprove_Click" />
```

and take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712642/android-scaling-of-button-with-background-image)

and why don't you use ImageButton instead:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/greybutton"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then you can adjust the scaling with the scaleType attribute. The only downside is you can't set any text.
good luck

Comment: I dont see how this helps, i need 4 *normal Buttons on top of* a bitmap. The culpit is having these scale along to match the bitmap position and scale.